# Russell's paradox and Cantor's theorem: regarding the construction of a set

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

There are lots of similar posts regarding this question, but none of those really address my question.

Russell's paradox: Let $R=\{x|x\notin x\}$ then $R\in R\iff R\notin R$

**Then when I am reading cantor's theorem, I thought it was Russell's paradox but it seems not exact the paradox itself.**

**Theorem**  If $A$ is any set, then $|A|\leq|\mathscr{P}(A)|$

Define injective : $$f:A\to\mathscr{P}(A)\\a\to\{a\}$$

There is no bijective $$g:A\to\mathscr{P}(A)$$
Assume there is an such bijective, define $S=\{a\in A|a\notin g(a)\}\subseteq A$. Since $S\in\mathscr{P}(A)$, $\color{red}{S=g(x)}$ for some $x\in A$ because $g$ is surjection. Then $x\in S\iff x\notin S$ and $x\notin S\iff x\in S$, contradiction bulit.

**My questions are sort of connected to each other, because I don't really get it, much appreciated if you can help me out sequentially**

**1.Russell's paradox says you cannot define a collection of set that do not contains the collection itself, then what about can you define a set that contains the set itself as a element? I think you also cannot do that. So when you define a set, you can neither let itself in the set, nor do not in the set???**

**2.Can one really defines a set that contains some elements not in the set? like $S=\{a\in A|a\notin S\}$, the set contains some elements not in this set itself? Isn't this already sort of contradiction?**

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: See Ivor Grattan-Guinness, [How Bertrand Russell discovered his paradox (1978)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0315086078900460) for link between Cantor's argument and Russell's paradox.

Comment: 1) not exactly; the assumption responsible for the paradox is that for every "specified" condition there is the corresponding *set*. See [Comprehension principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification#Unrestricted_comprehension)

Comment: 2) yes, we cannot use circular definitions, like $S= \{ x \mid \varphi(x) \text { and } x \notin S \}$

Comment: The short answer to your first question is that in Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory, a set cannot be an element of itself. This follows from the axiom of regularity. The short answer to your second question is that a set is determined by its elements, as stated in the axiom of extensionality. So a set that contains elements not in that set is an absurdity.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you for your reply. If we **cannot** use circular definitions, like $S=\{x|\phi(x) \land x\notin S\}$, why does Cantor's theorem proof involve that, in my above red colour content.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Moreover, it seems Russell's paradox is just built on axioms of regularity and axiom of comprehension?

Comment: No Russell's paradox is built on the "reasonable" assumption of intuitive set theory that for every specified condition there is the corresponding set. This assumption leads to contradiction, from which axiomatic set theory. With axioms like that of $\mathsf {ZF}$, where intuitive comprehension is replaced by Separation ("restricted" comprehension) we cannot reproduce Russell's paradox: the result is that we cannot prove the existence of the *universal* set (that in intuitive set theory is easily "specified"). egularity axiom is ivolved into rejecting the existence of sets such that $x \in x$.

Comment: Lacking Comprehension, we cannot apply the "specification" used by Russell in the definition $R= \{  x \mid x∉x \}$ because we have to use Specification that needs $R= \{  x \mid x \in A \text { and } x∉x \}$ and Russell's set needs the *universal* set as $A$ and there is none.

Comment: The definition $S = \{ a \in A \mid a \notin g(a) \}$ is *not* circular. You are defining a set $S$ in terms of another set $A$ and a bijection $g$. The definition of $A$ and $g$ does not in any way depend on $S$, so there is no circularity here.